# Changing x-axis scale in Asymptote graph

Tags: asymptote

I am using Asymptote's graph module.  How do I make the horizontal scale different than the vertical scale?

The FAQ tells me to use Linear, but I cannot seem to make it work for me.

Here is an example file.  The x-axis and the y-axis have the same distance between 0 and 1; how do I make the x-axis's distance be, say, half that of the y-axis?

```
include graph;
int picnum = 5;
picture p;
unitsize(p, 1.25cm);

xaxis(p,"$x$",YZero,
      xmin=-1,xmax=6,
      RightTicks(Label("$%.2g$",tickpen),
         new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,5}),  // Step=1,step=1),
             above=false); 
yaxis(p,"Probability",XEquals(-1),ymin=0,ymax=1.1,
      LeftTicks(Label("$%.2g$",tickpen),
        new real[]{0,1}, // Step=1,step=1,
        pTick=black, ptick=linetype("4 4")+grey,
         extend=false));
shipout(format("graph%02d",picnum),p,format="pdf");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Linear` has an optional argument : a multiplicative scaling factor.
In your case, I hope that the code is the desired one

include graph;
    int picnum = 5;
    picture p;
    unitsize(p, 1.25cm);

```
scale(p,Linear,Linear(2));

dot(p,Scale(p,(1,1)),red);

xaxis(p,"$x$",YZero,
      xmin=-1,xmax=6,
      RightTicks(Label("$%.2g$"),
                 new real[]{0,1,2,3,4,5}),  // Step=1,step=1),
      above=false); 
yaxis(p,"Probability",XEquals(-1),ymin=0,ymax=1.1,
      LeftTicks(Label("$%.2g$"),
                new real[]{0,1}, // Step=1,step=1,
                pTick=black, ptick=linetype("4 4")+grey,
                extend=false));



shipout(format("graph%02d",picnum),p,format="pdf");
```

Notice `dot(p,Scale(p,(1,1)),red);` to have the point (1,1) well placed.

[image]

O.G.